# Is `$var = $var + 0` an acceptable way to prevent SQL injection in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

A team I work with has a habit of escaping IDs and integers in SQL like this:

`$var = $var + 0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE id = $var";`

Is this an acceptable way to prevent SQL injection in PHP, or is it vulnerable?

Comment: Use prepared statement http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Best to just use prepared statements https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.html

Comment: That's a pretty poor attempt at type casting in PHP, especially since it emits a warning.  You should use `intval($var)` or `(int) $var` to type cast to an integer.  If it's casted to an integer, it is safe, but that's only valid protection for integer types.

Answer (score -2):

No its not a preventive way. Use PHP PDO. Read this:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp